# Kaminari paginate return nothing with non-empty data in params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

I just install gem Kaminari, for paginate my rails app. I used it like :

```
<%= paginate @topics %>
<div id="topics">
  <%= render @topics %>
</div>
```

in my view **views/topics/index.html.erb**

in my controller **TopicsController:**

```
def index
  @topics = Topic.order(score: :desc).page(params[:page] || 1).per(20)
end
```

page() and per() works.

The **partial of topics works**, my topics are shown, but nothing append for paginate instruction.

```
<%= paginate @topics %>returned "" (empty string)!
```

what is the problem?

Comment: once try adding `<%= paginate @topics %>` after partial render

Comment: @anusha nothing new. same, is empty.

Comment: Did this return any values `@topics = Topic.order(score: :desc)` or `empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in fact, if you have less than "per(X)" number in db, nothing shown. I thought there is always "1" number, but no...